# Can't find the database after publishing the application

Tags: mysql, vb.net, publish

Where can I find the database in my published application using visual basic 2010?

When I install the application using setup.exe the database is working but I don't know where the database is used or saved.

Inside the Application Files there's no database.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you installed to a `\Program Files` folder, Windows probably moved it under the  `\Users` Folder.

I think this varies depending on Windows version.

In my case, Windows stored it here:  `\USERS\myusername\Appdata\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\myProgramsName`.

You should be able to search for it with File Explorer.